# Dynamically change opacity of div in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to use the following Angular 2 code to dynamically change the opacity of a div.

The html looks like this:

```
<div [style.opacity]="buttonOpacity" class="likes">
    <ion-icon name="ios-heart"></ion-icon>
      {{theMediaItem.liked}} &nbsp;
    <ion-icon name="close-circle"></ion-icon>
      {{theMediaItem.disliked}} &nbsp;
</div>
```

In my Angular 2 ts file I have:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/veeu/veeu.html'
})
export class VeeUPage {

  buttonOpacity = 0.1;

  constructor(public nav : NavController) {

    this.buttonOpacity = 0.4;

  }
}
```

The opacity of the ion-icons doesn't change as it should.

Comment: either `buttonOpacity = 0.1` or `this.buttonOpacity = 0.4` should  be on a event? you are setting it directly then on a constructor, the change would be so fast it would hardly bee seen. Also is your use case that the opacity of component should be 0.4 from 0.1 when loaded?

Comment: I want the opacity change to stick. Neither of the opacity changes have any affect at the moment. Eventually I will put the opacity change in an if statement and change it from 0.4 to 1.0 and vice versa depending on a variable.

Comment: If you add it statically like `<div style="{opacity: 0.4}"`, does this result in the desired effect?

Comment: Thanks Gunter that helped me track down my error which was, to my shame, a cut and paste error! All works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your code, the value `0.4` is directly used I think because it's set in the constructor. That being said, I think you use the right approach to link a style to a class property.

You could try with a `setTimeout` to see if things change dynamically:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/veeu/veeu.html'
})
export class VeeUPage {
  buttonOpacity = 0.1;

  constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef, public nav : NavController) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.buttonOpacity = 0.4;
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });  
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the timeout has not affect. The icons remain unaffected by the attempt to change the opacity.

Comment: Is it the same if you try to explicitly force change detection with the `ChangeDetectorRef` and its `detectChanges` method?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. At present neither the opacity change to 0.1 or the one to 0.4 has any effect.

Comment: Where do I import ChengeDetectorRef from? What do you expect this to do?

Comment: From `@angular/core`. The call to the `detectChanges` will trigger change detection so it could update bindings in the template...

Answer (score 1):

Using **ngClass**
To add/remove classes in Angular, it's suggested to use the provided template syntax.

You can have something like this:

**Template**

**html:**

```
<button (click)="shouldShow = !shouldShow"> Show/Hide </button>
<label [ngClass]="{show: shouldShow, hide: !shouldShow}"> ... </label>
```

**Component**

// Make sure to add the variable in the component

```
public shouldShow = true;
```

The label will toggle between the show/hide css classes as the shouldShow variable changes from `true` to `false`

To get a simple fade in/out, you can add this **CSS**:

```
.show {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity 1s;
}

.hide {
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity 1s;
}
```